# for loop with structure+matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, data-structures

I have a structure named sacfile which has data for various stations within it (sta1-sta6). The sacfile is further borken up into day increments (sacfile.day, per station), and further into hourly increments for each day (sacfile.day.hour). I would like to loop through each day and subsequently through each hour for each station comparison (i.e., day 032 loop through sta1 hr 1 compared to sta2 hr 1, sta3 hr 1, sta4 hr1, sta5 hr1, sta6 hr 1, and so on and so forth through all the hours of that day, then move onto the next day, etc. You get the point. The stations are defined in sacfile.sta. Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can do this simply?

*I only want to loop through the same day and hour for the stations, then move onto the subsequent day and hour. I don't want to cross compare different days and hours. This is important for the loop.

I tried the following:

```
      for i = 1:length(sacfile)
          for j = 1:length(sacfile(i,1).day)
              for h = 1:length(sacfile(i,1).day.hour)
```

but that seems to loop through every hour point. Will this work, how can I be assured it's looping through the correct days, i.e., that day 1 for sta1 is the same day1 for sta2.

Here's an example of one of the structures:

```
        name: '2013.032.00.00.00.0000.TA.POKR..BHE.sac'
        date: '31-Mar-2014 12:25:33'
        bytes: 11949036
        isdir: 0
        datenum: 7.3569e+05
        net: 'TA'
        sta: 'POKR'
        loc: ''
        comp: 'BHE'
        day: [1x1 struct]
        data: [2987101x1 double]
        time: [1x2987101 double]
        header: [1x1 struct]
```

The only relevent ones are net, sta, loc, comp, day and data. The net, sta, loc, comp are the key identifying fields for the file. The name is the name of the file. Day has the data broken up into hours within it. Make sense?

Comment: language? attempts? errors?

Comment: I'm sorry I edited to include matlab. So far I just have it broken up into the days and hours. I'm struggling a bit as to the best way to loop through them. Every way I've tried doesn't seem to do it corretly. I tried:

Comment: Seems like you want to put your "hour" loop outside of the "day" loop, but obviously that won't work with the way your data is structured right now.

Comment: Are there any other fields in your structure? Show a small example.

Comment: You need to use an `if` statement within the inner `for` loop to check for equality of days and hours for both structures and do processing if that condition is true, and skip otherwise.

Comment: @yuk. I added commments in to address the structure. kavka I think the issue is that it is only looping through the first file. I guess to clarify I need to loop through hour 1 of file 1 and calculate things with hour1 of file 2, hour1 of file3, etc for the appropriate day...

Comment: Hmm..freude I'm not sure that's exactly what I wanted. I got the following error 'Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error.'

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem well, the functions `extractfield()` and `fieldnames()` should help.

```
fields = fieldnames(sacfile);

for i = 1:numel(fields)
    b = extractfield(sacfile.(fields{i}).day, 'day3');
    c(i) = extractfield(b{1}.hour, 'hour_x');
end
```

The function `extractfield()` returns 1x1 cell containing a structure instead of the structure itself. That is why I do `b{1}`

Comment: I believe for `extractfield` function you need Mapping Toolbox.